# What mean "Column '[field]' in field list is ambiguous in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

Hey I have a Problem in my SQL Statement

```
select Objektnr, AVG(Mieter.Miete) as "Durchschnitt Miete" from Objekt
join Wohnung on Objekt.Objektnr = Wohnung.Objektnr
join Mieter on Wohnung.Wohnungsnr=Mieter.Wohnungsnr
```

My Join don't work :(

Here is the Error: #1052 - Column 'Objektnr' in field list is ambiguous

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are saying you want to select the field `Objektnr`, but it exists in more than one table.  It's ambiguous because it doesn't know which one to pick from.  You need to fully qualify your column so that it knows which one to select - and since these are the same between the two tables (due to the `JOIN`), the following should work:

```
Select   Objekt.Objektnr, 
         AVG(Mieter.Miete) as "Durchschnitt Miete" 
From     Objekt
Join     Wohnung on Objekt.Objektnr = Wohnung.Objektnr
Join     Mieter  on Wohnung.Wohnungsnr = Mieter.Wohnungsnr
```

Answer (score 0):

means you have same field in diferent tables

just include the table before the field

```
select Objekt.Objektnr, AVG(Mieter.Miete) as "Durchschnitt Miete" from Objekt
join Wohnung on Objekt.Objektnr = Wohnung.Objektnr
join Mieter on Wohnung.Wohnungsnr=Mieter.Wohnungsnr
```